# Android: FATAL EXCEPTION: AdWorker #1 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.io.IOException.<init>

Tags: android, admob

Since a few weeks i am receiving the following crash reports from users

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: AdWorker #1
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.io.IOException.<init>
at com.google.android.gms.internal.g.f(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.g.b(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.e.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.e.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.bq.ac(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.cg$1.run(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.ch$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
```

Other than it has something to do with google ad/cloud services, i had no clue where it comes from. couldn't reproduce it till yesterday i started up a 10 inch emulator and saw immediately the problem. After removing parts of my code i identied to following piece to be the problem.

```
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ............

    AdView adView = (AdView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
    .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
    .addTestDevice("CED2A4FD2C192C08557081CC37AA9E54")
    .build();
     adView.loadAd(adRequest);
}
```

The strange thing is that it only happens on 10 inch devices or up. I tested on various different devices/versions. The problem only occurs on 10 inch devices or bigger. Android versions doesnt matter. 2.2 or 4.4 it keeps crashing.

To my understanding i dont have any different layout folders for specific device sizes.
the xml where my ad is defined looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:id="@+id/mainContainer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/titleContainer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <com.viewpagerindicator.TabPageIndicator
        android:id="@+id/indicator"
        style="@style/tabsbackground"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/adViewContainer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ads:adUnitId="@string/adid"
            ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I tried out different banner sizes. Doesnt help. Removing the ad request code solves the problem, but also removes the advertising.
Anyone a clue?

Comment: Have you tried setting layout_width to wrap_content for adview?

Comment: yes just tried it. still not working.

Comment: I have the exact same error, not for 10 inches devices, but for Froyo devices...

Comment: Does this happen if the AdView is not inside a ViewPager?

Comment: yes i tried the most minified setup. it is still crashing.
I think i know what the problem is. It is because the new Google Play Services does not support 2.2 and lower. There is a special Google Play Services for Froyo. But i cannot find a way to combine them. For now i simply check the API level of the user and switch of f ads if API is <=2.2. In my case 5% of the users

Comment: Yeah, the latest version of Google Play services, the one in which mobile ads were introduced, [dropped support for API 2.2](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/10/google-play-services-40.html).

Answer (score 12):

Google Mobile Ads is now offered through Google Play Services 4.0 and this error occurs because the Google Play Services is not available. Most likely you will run into this on Froyo, where there is a special version that can be used.

http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

> Note: Google Play services 4.0.30 (released November 2013) and newer
>   versions require Android 2.3 or higher. If your app supports Android
>   2.2, you can continue development with the Google Play services SDK, but must instead install Google Play services for Froyo from the SDK
>   Manager.

http:// android-developers.blogspot.no/2013/10/google-play-services-40.html

> With over 97% of devices now running Android 2.3 (Gingerbread) or
>   newer platform versions, we’re dropping support for Froyo from this
>   release of the Google Play services SDK in order to make it possible
>   to offer more powerful APIs in the future. That means you will not be
>   able to utilize these new APIs on devices running Android 2.2 (Froyo).

https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html#ensure

> Important: Because it is hard to anticipate the state of each device,
>   you must always check for a compatible Google Play services APK before
>   you access Google Play services features. For many apps, the best time
>   to check is during the onResume() method of the main activity.

Alernative 1 is to check if Google Play Services is available before using AdView.

```
int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext();
if(status == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
    //Success! Do what you want
}
```

Alernative 2 is to use GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.4.1.jar

Answer (score 0):

My experience with this bug did not seem to be related to Google Play Services not being available. 
The LogCat dump:

06-12 15:22:17.238: E/AndroidRuntime(5389): FATAL EXCEPTION: AdWorker #1

06-12 15:22:17.238: E/AndroidRuntime(5389): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.io.IOException.

06-12 15:22:17.238: E/AndroidRuntime(5389):     at com.google.android.gms.internal.k.f(Unknown Source)

indicates its a missing method used within AdWorker; and although I did not get any screen capture, I was able to use the Debugger to step through the error section and it seems that AdWorker is using String.isEmpty() which was only available for API-9 and after; so I crash when using my Samsung S1 API-8 test phone.